# Not able to add second TIMESTAMP colunm with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a table containing several TIMESTAMP columns.

Even if I'm not specifying `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for all TIMESTAMP columns I receive `#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause` error from phpmyadmin. So I can state that phpmyadmin implicitly uses `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value and attribute `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for the first TIMESTAMP column.

I suppose that this requirement (only one TIMESTAMP column can have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value) weird it self but the thing I really frustrated with is inability of creating more than one TIMESTAMP columns with phpmyadmin.

Is it phpmyadmin bug? (I doubt that phpmyadmin can have such bugs)

Is it phpmyadmin feature?

Am I able to bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

Only one INT is allowed to have the AUTO_INCREMENT modifier.

In like fashion, only one TIMESTAMP would be allowed to have the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP modifier.

If you need multiple TIMESTAMPs, all such columns should be defined as DATETIME or TIMESTAMP without the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

If you can and paste this

```
select version();
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
USE mydb
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ts1  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ts2  TIMESTAMP,
    dt1 DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    dt2 DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable\G
```

you get this

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.6.21    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.23 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE mydb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE mydb
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE mytable
    -> (
    ->     id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     ts1  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->     ts2  TIMESTAMP,
    ->     dt1 DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->     dt2 DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: mytable
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ts1` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ts2` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `dt1` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dt2` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

You cannot have multiple TIMESTAMPs with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

You can have multiple DATETIMEs with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

**Give it a Try !!!**

For more info, please read [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) from the MySQL Documentation.

In terms of phpmyadmin, it is at the mercy of mysql. If mysql does not allow this, phpmyadmin won't either.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But creating table with SQL statement is working OK. The question is mostly about phpmyadmin.

Comment: This issue is about MySQL only. Phpmyadmin is just adhering to MySQL.

Comment: Hm... Try to create a table in phpmyadmin with more that one TIMESTAMP column - it will not do it. However you CAN do it with SQL query.

Comment: You can have multiple TIMESTAMPs, but only one TIMESTAMP can have `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.6.21. It allows for multiple timestamps. Look at the 5.6 doc (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) and the 5.5 doc (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html) and see the difference.

Comment: THAT'S RIGHT! MySQL allows it and I absolutely agree with you. Phpmyadmin is not allowing me to do it.

Comment: You should upgrade to the latest phpmyadmin. The drivers used should adhere to mysql 5.6 now